# WKInterfaceButton multiple line title

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch, wkinterfacebutton

How can I show a three to four line title in a WKInterfaceButton?
I tried setting the size to fit content but it only shows a maximum of two lines for the title.

Comment: do you want multiline text actionable...??? are you???

Comment: i want it actionable. i know i can add WKInterfaceLabel in WKInterfaceButton but is there a way that i can change just number of lines like we do on iphone

Comment: yes we can if we Change `WKInterfaceButton` content type to Group. then add a  `WKinterfaceLabel` in it. set both of the objects height to "size to fit content".

Comment: did you try this...???

Comment: i know this solution, i want to know is there a solution without adding a label in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82775/discussion-between-zubair-and-developer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want multiline actionable text in your storyboard.

For now we can not make the multiline title of the `WKInterfaceButton`. But there is another work around that is helpful and recommended by *Apple* too.

Change the `Content` type of the `WKInterfaceButton` from *Text* to *Group*.

Make sure its height is "Size To Fit Content".

Now Add a `WKInterfaceLabel` in this Group. Make this Label's proper IBOutlet Connection. Put your Title *actionable* Text in this Label. Make sure Label's height is "Size To Fit Content" too.

Answer (score -1):

For people using Xamarin, right-click on your storyboard file, and open it in Xcode Interface Builder. Click on the the label, and set the "Lines" property to 2 (or more). And make sure the size of it is set to "Size to fit content", same with any parent container/group. These properties aren't visible in code for some reason.